# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++

Here is my code and it's giving the above mentioned error in 3rd line...

**ambisonic_3d.h**

```
#ifndef __DEF_HOA_3D_AMBISONIC__
#define __DEF_HOA_3D_AMBISONIC__

#include "Hoa.h"
//! The 3D ambisonic classes.
/**
 All the 3D ambisonic and planewaves classes will be part of this namespace
 */
namespace Hoa3D
{
    //! The ambisonic class.
    /** The ambisonics classes inherit from this classe. It computes the number of harmonics depending of the decomposition order and sorts the arguments and the bands of the harmonics in arrays.
     */
    class Ambisonic
    {
    protected:
        unsigned int    m_order;
        unsigned int    m_number_of_harmonics;
        unsigned int*   m_harmonics_degrees;
        int*            m_harmonics_orders;

    public:

        //! The ambisonic constructor.
        /** The ambisonic constructor allocates and initializes the generale member values depending of a decomposition order. The order must be at least 1.

            @param     order    The order.
         */
        Ambisonic(unsigned int order);

        //! The ambisonic destructor.
        /** The ambisonic destructor free the memory.
         */
        ~Ambisonic();

        //! Retrieve the decomposition order.
        /** Retrieve the decomposition order of an ambisonic class.
         */
        inline unsigned int getDecompositionOrder() const {return m_order;};

        //! Retrieve the number of harmonics.
        /** Retrieve the number of harmonics of an ambisonic class.
         */
        inline unsigned int getNumberOfHarmonics() const {return m_number_of_harmonics;};

        //! Retrieve the order of an harmonic.
        /** The order of an harmonic is in the range -degree to degree. The harmonics are sorted by their bands, from 0 to the decomposition order. In each band contains 2 * band + 1 harmonics, sorted by their arguments in the range -band to band. The harmonic input and output arrays in process method of ambisonic classes must have this configuration.
            For the first bands, the harmonics arrangement is h[0, 0] h[1, 0] h[1, -1] h[1, 1] h[2, 0] h[2, -1] h[2, 1] h[2, -2] h[2, 2] etc.
            with h[band, argument].

            @param     index    The global index of an harmonic.
            @return    The method returns the argument of the harmonic if the harmonic exists, otherwise the function generates an error.
            @see       getHarmonicDegree()
            @see       getHarmonicName()
         */
        inline int getHarmonicOrder(const unsigned int index) const
        {
            assert(index < m_number_of_harmonics);
            return m_harmonics_orders[index];
        };

        //! Retrieve the degree of an harmonic.
        /** The degree of the harmonics are in the range 0 to the decomposition order. Each degree contains 2 * degree + 1 harmonics in the range -degree to degree. The harmonic input and output arrays in process method of ambisonic classes must have this configuration.
            For the first bands, the harmonics arrangement is h[0, 0] h[1, 0] h[1, -1] h[1, 1] h[2, 0] h[2, -1] h[2, 1] h[2, -2] h[2, 2] etc.
            with h[band, argument].

            @param     index    The global index of an harmonic.
            @return    The method returns the band of the harmonic if the harmonic exists, otherwise the function generates an error.
            @see       getHarmonicOrder()
            @see       getHarmonicName()
         */
        inline unsigned int getHarmonicDegree(const unsigned int index) const
        {
            assert(index < m_number_of_harmonics);
            return m_harmonics_degrees[index];
        };

        //! Retrieve the index of an harmonic.
        /** The degree of the harmonics are in the range 0 to the decomposition order. Each degree contains 2 * degree + 1 harmonics in the range -degree to degree. The harmonic input and output arrays in process method of ambisonic classes must have this configuration.
         For the first bands, the harmonics arrangement is h[0, 0] h[1, -1] h[1, 0] h[1, 1] h[2, -2] h[2, -1] h[2, 0] h[2, 1] h[2, 2] etc.
         with h[degree, order].

         @param     degree  The degree an harmonic.
         @param     order   The order an harmonic.
         @return    The method returns the index of the harmonic if the harmonic exists, otherwise the function generates an error.
         @see       getHarmonicOrder()
         @see       getHarmonicName()
         */
        inline unsigned int getHarmonicIndex(const unsigned int degree, const int order) const
        {
            assert(degree <= m_order);
            return degree * degree + degree + order;
        };

        //! Retrieve a name for an harmonic.
        /** Retrieve a name for an harmonic in a std::string format that will be "harmonic band argument".

            @param     index    The global index of an harmonic.
            @return    The method returns a name for the harmonic that contains its band and its argument if the harmonic exists, otherwise the function generates an error.
            @see       getHarmonicDegree()
            @see       getHarmonicOrder()
         */
        inline std::string getHarmonicName(const unsigned int index) const
        {
            assert(index < m_number_of_harmonics);
            return "Harmonic " + int_to_string(getHarmonicDegree(index)) + " " + int_to_string(getHarmonicOrder(index));
        };
    };
}

#endif
```

this is my **`Hoa.h`** file:

```
#ifndef __DEF_HOA_LIBRARY__
#define __DEF_HOA_LIBRARY__

namespace Hoa{};

#include "HoaDefs.h"
#include "HoaMath.h"
#include "HoaUtils.h"

using namespace Hoa;

#endif
```

and the **visual studio** log is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ambisonics, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>Decoder_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Encoder_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Map_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Meter_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\planewaves_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Optim_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Planewaves_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\planewaves_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Rotate_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Scope_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Vector_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\planewaves_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Wider_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Ambisonic_3D.cpp
1>f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\ambisonic_3d.h(10) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Hoa.h': No such file or directory
1>Generating Code...
1>Build log was saved at "file://f:\Jayakar\ToJayakar\Ambisonics_module\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>ambisonics - 11 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Are `program1.cpp` (and the other `.cpp` files in the log) and `Hoa.h` located in the same directory?

Comment: Yes both are located in same folder

Comment: And `ambisonic_3d.h` and `planewaves_3d.h`? (Actually, I can't see `program1.cpp` anywhere in the log. What makes you think *that* file has an error in the first place?)

Comment: sorry, Biffen, I've edited it now... For info purpose i named it as program1 it's actually ambisonic_3d.h

Comment: So there's definitely a file at `f:\jayakar\tojayakar\hoa3d\Hoa.h`? If there is then there's not much one can do to help without more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In place of #include "Hoa.h" provide complete path and try.

Comment: Thanks venky...Do you know anything about missing stdint.h library

Comment: Itis usually not a good idea to provide absolute paths in the source code. It is better to tell the compiler/linker in which directories it should be looking at.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin... I've added that folder path to the project